# Struts 1: How may I pass data between Actions?

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I'm trying to pass data between 2 `Action` classes. I'm currently doing this

In my first Action class

```
doExecute(){
         request.setAttribute("Order_ID", 2);
         // code to find forward to next Action class
}
```

In the following Action class

```
doExecute(){
     Object id = request.getAttribute("Order_ID");
     // code to process id
}
```

However, the `getAttribute()` method always returns null. How can I property pass data between 2 action forms that follow each other?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your ultimate purpose? How is it that they "follow each other"? Normally you'd put data that must persist across requests into the session, or into hidden form fields.

Comment: My ultimate purpose is just to be able to send a dynamically generated variable (eg 2) from the first Action to the next action the mapping.findForward() takes it to. I'm trying setting it as an attribute in the request so I could retrieve it in the next action. I'm quite novice at Struts so please do feel free to correct my understanding.

Comment: If the second action is following the first in the same request then what you are doing should work. Is your first action doing a redirect? If so then you'll have a new request in the second action so you'll need to pass the value as a parameter included in the URL your redirect to (or stick it in the session, which is not a great solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are number of ways , you can do this.

**Method 1:**

Set the attribute in session and then get the value back and then remove it from session.

```
doExecute(){

 HttpSssion session=request.getSession();
 session.setAttribute("Order_ID", 2);
}
```

then return it back.

```
doExecute(){

 HttpSssion session=request.getSession();
 Object id =session.getAttribute("Order_ID");
 session.removeAttribute("Order_ID");
}
```

**Method 2:**

Pass the value in url and then get it back from other action but here need to keep in mind that your request doesn't loss.

For more please refer below link.

http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/Servlet-Tutorial-Session-Tracking.html

Answer (score 0):

in you're in session mode, than hold the data you want to transfer inside your actionForm, then you don't need to setAttribute/getAttribute.